# Error using Estimator export_saved_model (Not found: Key global_step not found in checkpoint)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to prepare a pre-trained model for google cloud ML. I am trying to use an estimator to export the model. During the loading of the checkpoints by the estimator I get the following error:

```
2018-11-19 13:28:57.526564: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Not found: Key global_step not found in checkpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key global_step not found in checkpoint
         [[{{node save_1/RestoreV2}} = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save_1/Const_0_0, save_1/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

- TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.12.0
- Python version: 3.6

Here is the code I am using:

```
MODEL_DIR='model/'
def decode_image(image_bytes):
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image_bytes)
    image = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.uint8)
    return image

def serving_input_fn():
    createmodel()
    inputs = {'image_bytes': tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(), name="image_bytes")}
    imagebytes = tf.squeeze(inputs['image_bytes']) # make it a scalar
    image = decode_image(imagebytes)
    # make the outer dimension unknown (and not 1)
    image = tf.placeholder_with_default(image, shape=[None, None, None, 3])

    features = {'image_bytes' : image}
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, inputs)

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("fc1_voc12:0")
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT,
        predictions=pred,
        export_outputs={'pred':tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(pred)}
        )

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir=MODEL_DIR)

estimator.export_savedmodel('deployment_gcp_1', serving_input_fn, strip_default_attrs=True)
```

I have searched this issue quite a bit. There was one bug report for an older version of tensorflow (I think 1.2.0 but I am not sure now). I am able to load and save this model using tf.saved_model.simple_save, and it works when I run predictions on it.

I am not sure if this is a bug or if I am missing something really simple. I have posted the same thing on the tensorflow github repo but no responses there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to get it to work by adding the "global_step" variable manually, exporting that as a new checkpoint and loading that instead.
After loading the current checkpoint I ran the following code:

```
b = tf.Variable(load_step, name="global_step", dtype=tf.int64)
sess.run(b.initializer)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess,'UpdatedModel/model.ckpt', global_step=load_step)
```

Then in my previous code I used the new folder MODEL_DIR and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, where you minimize the loss using any optimizer,

```
train_op = optimizer.minimize( loss , global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
```

You might not have mentioned the `global_step=` due to which you get the error.

Comment: There was no optimizer in my code. I used the following model for training: https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet

Comment: If you are using your model at some point then can you provide that code ?

Comment: This turned out to be a bug in tensorflow. I will post more details after I get more details.